# Somar valores de uma coluna na tabela

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, mysqli, select

Preciso selecionar os 3 usuários com maior receita. Antes na tabela **cde_usuario** havia uma coluna chamada **qtdreceita**, sendo bem simples de fazer essa consulta, utilizava esse sql:

```php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM cde_usuario ORDER BY qtdreceita DESC LIMIT 3";
```

Porém, essa coluna foi removida, pois agora existe a tabela **cde_venda_detalhe**, sendo umas das colunas **id_cliente** e **valor**. Agora preciso somar todos os números da coluna **valor** de todos os clientes com compras, e no final selecionar os 3 clientes que resultaram no maior valor.

Sei que para somar o valor total de todas as compras de um usuário específico é assim:

```php
$sql = "SELECT SUM(valor) as total FROM cde_venda_detalhe WHERE id_cliente = $idCliente";
```

Porém não sei como "unir" esses SELECTs, se alguém puder me ajudar agradeço.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avalie se é isto o que deseja:

```
SELECT id_cliente, SUM(valor) as total FROM cde_venda_detalhe GROUP BY id_cliente ORDER BY total DESC LIMIT 3;
```

Comment: Sim, funcionou perfeitamente, obrigado!